# Python error using Vterrain in qgis

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, 3d

Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/Haimwant/.qgis2/python/plugins\VTerrain\VTerrain.py", line 409, in run
                os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, directory + "Enviro", "-terrain=" + terrain)
              File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\os.py", line 608, in spawnl
                return spawnv(mode, file, args)
            OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory[image: Python error using Vterrain]

Comment: When you do a ls/cd on the file does it exists? If not check the permissions